# Is Ngx-bootstrap compatible with angular 13 and bootstrap v3

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap-3, ngx-bootstrap, slim-lang, angular13

My project was working with angular 11 and bootstrap v3 but since I updated angular to v13 my ruby project although building spits out runtime ActionView:Template errors such as:

```
actionview (6.1.4) lib/action_view/template.rb, line 314
```

which tells me that the (compile &) render template method in ruby is tripping an error.

FYI the compatibility table from:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap#compatibility
```

goes as far as: Angular 10 with Bootstrap v3

Comment: The compatibility table is outdated, see the up-to-date table [here](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap#compatibility). That table only goes until Angular 12, so Angular 13 is not yet supported.